how to swap table results at the end of long running function
We have a function that builds a summary table and takes about 50-130 secs on average depending on data like so
Truncate table summaryTable ;

-- multiple insert statements and couple of loops...
insert into summaryTable .....

The process fails at times too, so changing it to
Truncate table tempsummaryTable ;

-- multiple insert statements and couple of loops...
insert into tempsummaryTable .....

-- if all goes well
Truncate table summaryTable ;
insert into summaryTable SELECT * FROM tempsummaryTable ;

The docs here state there's no begin transaction in PostgreSQL, so would this work as-is, or is there another way to ensure the integrity of data in summarytable ?
To reiterate - goal is to have a working copy of the data in summarytable at all times, rebuild the contents as needed in a temp table and replace the contents in a quick operation with minimal downtime, if the process fails for any reason then the summarytable data remains intact
Again - the goal is not to drop / alter / rename table but to switch the dataset with minimal issues
Currently using 16.2, will move to 17 when available on AWS

"the docs here state there's no begin transaction in postgresql" -> Quote from the link you provided: "A new transaction is started automatically after a transaction is ended using these commands, so there is no separate START TRANSACTION command.". May I ask exactly what you understood from this sentence?

Anyway, your real problem, if you ask me, is the truncate. Quote: "TRUNCATE is not MVCC-safe. After truncation, the table will appear empty to concurrent transactions, if they are using a snapshot taken before the truncation occurred."

Wouldn't it be just as good to DROP TABLE temp, ALTER TABLE .sum RENAME TO temp and CREATE TABLE sum LIKE temp?

@Atmo I had to lookup MVCC, I'm new to postgresql, previously used MSSQL, hence the question how to safely run this process

@TimRoberts there are constant queries on summarytable that might fail between drop rename and alter, trying to avoid that

This is essentially a duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75212974/postgresql-how-to-safely-rename-table).

This question is similar to: Postgresql - How to safely rename table. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Looks like you’d be better off using a materialized view

I would personally go for 1. truncating/reinserting into the temp table, in a properly isolated transaction and 2. refreshing summarytable as a materialized view (without the CONCURRENTLY option if the update is short/executed outside of busy hours, with it otherwise). IMO, this is the easiest way to make summarytable look like it is never emptied out.

@Atmo you gave me an idea, how about just using a regular view instead, and change the definition to temp when processing is complete, do the truncate and insert into summary and switch the view definition back to summary, that way view always points to a valid data, that way there shouldn't be any potential safety issues imho

@JohnH  it's similar but not the same, the goal here is not to drop and rename but to switch the dataset with minimal potential issues and downtime, Atmo here gave an idea that works better than drop and rename, will check it out

@Kumar, this is not equivalent to a materialized view as a regular view would be temporarily empty at some point during the update. A materialized view should guarantee you that never happens, Though this guarantee may come at the cost of blocking concurrent queries, you know the data will always be fine.

@Atmo the view is not empty as there's data in the summary table and then the temp table while the summary is truncated and rehydrated and switched to the summary again, this obviates the blocking concurrent queries issue as well

Ah, I see your answer. So... OK, in tht way, the view is never empty but that is replacing 1 REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW query for 4 queries + I strongly believe this solution cannot be executed concurrently with other transactions.

I would keep two tables with identical definition around: summarytable and summarytable_x.  The latter is always empty. Then the operation would work like this:
-- insert new data into summarytable_x
INSERT INTO summarytable_x ...

-- rename the original summary table
-- this will block if there are concurrent transactions
ALTER TABLE summarytable RENAME TO summarytable_old;

-- complete the swap
ALTER TABLE summarytable_x RENAME TO summarytable;
ALTER TABLE summarytable_old RENAME TO summarytable_x;
TRUNCATE summarytable_x;

When you rename summarytable, make sure that there are no long-running statements or transactions using it, because they would block the renaming, which in turn would block all other concurrent access to the table.

Thanks to @atmo for the idea about using views
so all queries go against the view on summarytable and meanwhile the function is changed to
Truncate table tempsummaryTable ;

-- multiple insert statements and couple of loops...
insert into tempsummaryTable .....

-- if all goes well
CREATE or REPLACE view vw_summary as SELECT * FROM tempsummaryTable;

Truncate table summaryTable ;
insert into summaryTable SELECT * FROM tempsummaryTable ;

CREATE or REPLACE view vw_summary as SELECT * FROM summaryTable;

and the view will always point to valid data
